# increment base value python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, increment

How do I increment a base value each time "i" is looped in a for loop?
The logic is something like:

```
fruits = [bananas, apples, pears]
total_fruits_count = 0

for i in fruits:
    ## some code resolveing fruit count ##
    local_fruit_count = 1
    total_fruits_count + local_fruit_count

print total_fruits_count
```

With this code, total_fruits_count just ends up being 0. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the value of `total_fruits_count`.

```
fruits = ["bananas", "apples", "pears"]
total_fruits_count = 0

for i in fruits:
    local_fruit_count = 1
    total_fruits_count += local_fruit_count

print total_fruits_count
```

In your original code, you did `total_fruits_count + local_fruit_count`, which calculates the sum of the two, but doesn't do anything with it.  the plus-equals shortcut `+=` adds the values and stores it in the left variable, `total_fruits_count`.

Comment: @Arash If you liked my answer, could you please clicked the upvote triangle above the 0 vote count and the checkmark under it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This just calculates the sum and discards the result

```
total_fruits_count + local_fruit_count
```

You need the `=` in there to assign the result back to `total_fruits_count`

```
total_fruits_count += local_fruit_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use enumerate function or len depending on what You need

```
fruits = ["bananas", "apples", "pears"]
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
     print "fruit with index %d is '%s'" % (i, fruit)

total_fruits_count = len(fruits)
```